# Xcode cannot find node

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode

Attempting to use node in a Build Phase in Xcode fails.

Adding a new build Phase with the following script, to a newly create Xcode project:
`node -v`

[image: Screenshot from Xcode Build Phase]

Results in the following error when attempting to build the project:

```
/Users/my-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NodePlay-gsxizuhznxbjnfcbiujdrclrhknv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/NodePlay.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NodePlay.build/Script-4E0D44FA2913BD480032430C.sh: line 2: node: command not found
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

When running `which node` and `node -v` in the terminal, I get valid responses. Opening Xcode through the terminal doesn't help. I've installed node through nvm. I've matched my setup with a colleague, that also have node installed in a similar way through nvm. He's able to build a similar new app with out these errors.

Any ideas are much welcome!

Comment: Terminal's PATH is not Xcode's PATH. Look at the build log. All environment variables are listed. Look at PATH. Does it include the place where `node` is? Clearly not. So don't say `node`. Say the full path that you got from `which node`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as matt commented, the issue was the difference between `PATH` in Xcode vs. Terminal. Running `echo $PATH` in both the Build Phase and the terminal revealed the difference.

Xcode didn't have `/Users/my-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin:` in it's `PATH` which the terminal did.

I resolved the issue by creating a Symlink to the nvm node version inside `usr/bin/local` like so:

```
sudo ln -s /Users/my-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
```